# How to implement a click through in custom HTML mode in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to implement in an extension something similar to a Go To Definition in a HTML template.

For example, ctrl-clicking on the path would open an editor with the file at this path:

```
{% include "relative/path/to/snippet.html" %}
```

Do you have any pointers to relevant documentation, on any repo doing something similar?

I’m pretty new to VSCode extensions and total newbee to Intellisense, so I would need some examples.

I guess it would include:

1. Parsing the HTML/text file to find the relevant clickable zone
2. Tell IntelliSense to do something fancy
3. Implement the fancy stuff (I’ll figure out this part eventually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is powered by a [`DefinitionProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#DefinitionProvider). Your extension can create a custom definition provider that only returns results for the paths you are interested in. The provider would be registered using `registerDefinitionProvider` for the `html` language mode

This would look something like:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as path from 'path'

class MyProvider implements vscode.DefinitionProvider {
    provideDefinition(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Definition> {

        const linkText = getLinkText(document, position); // implement this

        if (! linkText) { 
            return null;
        }

        const workspace = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(document.uri);
        const root = workspace ? workspace.uri : document.uri;

        return new vscode.Location(
            root.with({
                path: path.join(root.path, linkText)
            }),
            new vscode.Position(0, 0));
    }
}

vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider('html', new MyProvider());
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed some time to know how to plug in and understand how it works. I started my extension as a Language Support and then missed dev dependencies in my package.json and the entry point.

Comment: Does the extension need to register contributing languages for this to work? I can't seem to get my provider loaded for JSON files